# Join dataframes if key could be in multiple columns

Tags: r

I'd appreciate some help to solve this problem.

**Data** - I have two dataframes (df1 and df2 below). In df2, each row is an individual subject and they may or may not have one or more associated samples in the 4 sample columns (sample_a, sample_b etc). In df2, each sample number is unique so only appears once. Most subjects only have one associated sample (some have none) so they are in sample_a column but some have more than one so they are in sample_a, sample_b etc.

**Goal** - For each sample_id in df1, I would like to find the sample_id in df2, then copy across some info from that subject's row ("subject" and "house") to df1 whilst also keeping the column "value" in df1. See intended outcome below.

**So far/question** - I tried using dplyr::left_join as below which works well for those that only have a single associated sample but its not looking in the other sample columns i.e. sample_b, sample_c. So in the "intended outcome" example below, row 3 would have NA for subject and house. Is there a way to match sample_id across multiple columns? Or is there a better alternative approach?

```
dplyr::left_join(df1, df2, by = c("sample_id" = "sample_a")
```

**Example data**

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  sample_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  value = c(4351, 342, 235, 49, 10293))

df2 <- data.frame(
  subject = c("001", "002", "003", "004", "005"),
  house = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
  sample_a = c(1, 2, NA, 4, 5),
  sample_b = c(NA, 3, NA, NA, NA),
  sample_c = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
  sample_d = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

**Intended outcome**

```
df3 <- data.frame(
  sample_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  value = c(4351, 342, 235, 49, 10293),
  subject = c("001", "002", "002", "004", "005"),
  house = c("a", "b", "b", "d","e"))
```

Many thanks for your help

Thom

Comment: [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) your data so that samples are in a key/value pair.  Then your life will become easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the same key value in both data frames before merging them.

A tidyverse solution below:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df2_long <- df2 %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("sample"), 
               values_to = "sample_id") %>% 
  select(-name)

left_join(df1, df2_long, by = "sample_id")
```

Output:

```
  sample_id value subject house
1         1  4351     001     a
2         2   342     002     b
3         3   235     002     b
4         4    49     004     d
5         5 10293     005     e
```

Comment: That works, thank you very much, I was definitely over complicating things.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner using `reshape2::melt` and `merge`.

```
merge(df1, reshape2::melt(df2, 1:2)[-3], by.x='sample_id', by.y='value')
#   sample_id value subject house
# 1         1  4351     001     a
# 2         2   342     002     b
# 3         3   235     002     b
# 4         4    49     004     d
# 5         5 10293     005     e
```